# Sitecore/GlassMapper get the page

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

I'm working with Sitecore 8.1 and GlassMapper to map the fields in C#. 
I'm using datasources for the developed components.

I need to be able to take a field from the page we are currently in. Do you know how can I get the page object defined in Sitecore?

Comment: Using webforms or mvc?

Comment: Can't you use the GetCurrentItem on the Glass Sitecore context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example if you have a Home page and field Title
  you cast your current page to HomePage model

```
  var context = new SitecoreContext();
  Model = context.GetCurrentItem<HomePage>();
```

Where Model is defined like: 
      public HomePage Model { get; set; }

And in your view you will have:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<Namespace.HomePage>

 <title>@Model.Title</title>
```

Please check also this link: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12

If you want to make it editable in Page Editor you can use:

http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial14

Comment: When calling from a GlassController, the wrapper method is `GetContextItem<T>()`. Underneath it calls SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<T>()